# Impedir que o autocomplete jquery-ui aceite palavras que não estão na lista

Tags: jquery-ui

Quero fazer com que meu autocomplete do input não aceite nenhuma palavra que não esteja numa lista.Estou usando o código abaixo, tirado do próprio site do jQuery-ui 1.12.1.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }
 
    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          return false;
        }
      });
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
  <input id="tags" size="50">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode adicionar novos eventos verificando se a palavra digitada existe na lista, que é uma array. Caso a palavra não esteja na lista, ela é excluída do campo.

Adicionei dois eventos `blur` e `mouseleave` para disparar a função (veja comentários no código):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Multiple values</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
  
  function remDup(){

      // remove duplicadas
      var tags = $("#tags").val().split(",");
      var dup = [];
      $.each(tags, function(i, e) {
         if($.inArray(e.trim(), dup) == -1) dup.push(e.trim());
      });
      $("#tags").val(dup.join(", "));
  }
  
  $( function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];
    function split( val ) {
      return val.split( /,\s*/ );
    }
    function extractLast( term ) {
      return split( term ).pop();
    }
 
    $( "#tags" )
      // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
      .on( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
            $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      })

      // AQUI ONDE COLOQUEI A FUNÇÃO
      .on( "blur mouseleave", function(){ // capturo os eventos
         var tags = $( this ).val().split(","); // converto o valor do campo em array
         var invs = [];
         for(let item of tags){ // percorro a array da lista procurando os valores do campo
             if(availableTags.indexOf(item.trim()) != -1){ // não achou na lista
               invs.push(item);
             }
         }
         invs.push("");
         this.value = invs.join(",")+" ";

      })
      
          
      .autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: function( request, response ) {
          // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
          response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
            availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {
          // prevent value inserted on focus
          return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          var terms = split( this.value );
          // remove the current input
          terms.pop();
          // add the selected item
          terms.push( ui.item.value );
          // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
          terms.push( "" );
          this.value = terms.join( ", " );
          remDup();
          return false;
        }
      })
      
      remDup();
  });
  
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tag programming languages: </label>
  <input id="tags" value="Java, Java, C, " size="50">
  <br>
   <input type="button" value="Verificar" onclick="verificar()">
</div>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, @dvd. Entendi perfeitamente. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: só mais uma dúvida. Agora falando sobre valores duplicados. Tipo, quero que, quando no campo a houver um dos itens da lista, ele não pode ser adicionado de novo. E também caso o campo ja inicie com valores default, como faria para evitar duplicação? Grato!

Comment: @AntonioBrazFinizola Atualizei o todo o código que havia colocado antes e adicionei uma função para remover as duplicadas.

Comment: Blz, @dvd. Irei agora mesmo testar. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Outra dúvida, @dvd. Como faço para impedir que o usuário digite qualquer coisa que não esteja na tabela? Tipo, o usuário ser obrigado a digitar algum dos valores existentes na lista?